# Materialize - Autocomplete does not show options instantly

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, materialize

I have a problem with Materialize's autocomplete form.
I'am using it within a card. But the options are not shown instantly.
For example, while typing a 'G' the autocomplete form should suggest 'Google'. But it doesn't. Only by mouseclicking on the form the autocomplete options are shown. But I can not locate a mistake.

HTML (there is just one autocomplete form on this page):

```
   <div id="referenceSetCard"  class="row">>
        <div class="col s12 m4 l4 offset-m4 offset-l4">
            <div class="card over-all">
                <!-- Title -->
                <div class="card-action red darken-4 white-text">
                    <h4>Header</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Content -->
                <div class="card-content">
                    <p>Text</p>
                    <!-- Input field -->
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input id="referenceDataInput" type="text" class="autocomplete">
                            <label for="referenceDataInput">Autocomplete</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Buttons -->
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a id="buttonConfirm" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red hide-on-med-and-down">
                            Confirm
                        </a>
                        <a id="buttonCancel" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red hide-on-med-and-down">
                            Cancel
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "Apple": null,
                "Microsoft": null,
                "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
            },
        });
    });
```

Just have a look:

https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/zLoaJE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use these new versions of cdnjs or minified scripts.

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

You can also change the value of `minLength` like when you want autocomplete dropdown to popup.

[Codepen of Autocomplete with V 1.0.0-rc.2](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/yqVqJo)

[Codepen of your code with V 1.0.0-rc.2](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/yqVqJo)

Comment: Thank you. Realized I was using 1.0.0-rc.1, so with rc.2 and jq 3.3.1 it works for me.

Comment: I was also changing things like minLength and other things but didn't checked the versions of scripts and by changing those it worked XD

Answer (score 0):

I have forked and updated the Pen you made and here's the link for the codepen:

```
codepen.io/immad-hamid/pen/ajBjXx
```

I have change the version of the scripts and it's working now. May be there's an issue of jQuery version. Now you have a working demo so you can try out with changing the versions.

Comment: You've downgraded the versions of scripts, and why would a person use the old versions, what if the old versions got bugs in other parts?

Comment: Yeah, the thing is we should keep up with the newer veresions of the scripts, old versions are discarded because they're having bugs.

Comment: In my answer I told the the person who asked the question that you have a working demo, now you can play around and change the versions... Anyway its working now and good luck...